# asp binding returning wrong value from database

Tags: asp.net, ms-jet-ace

When I bind a url using the productID field from my access database it returns the wrong value for example as my database starts with the first field as 2 it returns -1, then -2 for 3 and so on.

```
<a href='details.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("ProductID") %>'>
```

thanks

Comment: I dont know wats the problem.. but i tried this and it works perfectly.., < a href='details.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("ID") %>'>test< /a> ,check your db, the column name, the inputted data..

Answer (score 0):

Try `<a href="details.aspx?ID='<%#Eval("ProductID") %>'">`

or

use asp hyperlink

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server"
 NavigateUrl='details.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("ProductID") %>'
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<a href="details.aspx?ID='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductId")%>'">
```